# $\arcsin(\sin(5\pi/4))$

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

Having trouble with this question

> $\arcsin(\sin(5\pi/4))$

wouldn't the arcsin and sin cancel each other out, therefor this would just equal $5\pi/4$. the answer in the back of my book is $-\pi/4$.

Comment: Notice that the range of $\arcsin $ is $-\pi/2\leq 0\leq\pi/2$

Comment: This is an experiment which has to be carried out at least once in a lifetime: plot the graph of $\arcsin(\sin x)$ over a large interval. ($\arcsin$ is always bounded between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, so it is pretty clear the answer *cannot* be $5\pi/4$)

Answer (score 3):

We have $\sin(\arcsin x)=x$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$, and $\arcsin(\sin x)=x$ for all $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.  The key, important difference is that $\sin(\arcsin x)$ is *only* defined for $x\in[-1,1]$, while $\arcsin(\sin x)$ is defined for *all* real $x$.  The latter's unlimited domain is the source of many a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$\arcsin(x)$ is a number whose sine is $x$. But there are a lot of numbers whose sine is $x$, so which one is $\arcsin(x)$? The values of $\sin(x)$ are generally between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, which ensures that for every $x$ (between $-1$ and $1$), there is exactly one answer. So the question is asking which angle between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ has a sine equal to $\sin(5\pi/4)$?

Answer (score 1):

$\sin\left( \frac{5\pi}{4} \right)= - \sqrt{\frac12}$

$\arcsin \left( - \sqrt{\frac12} \right) = -\frac{\pi}{4}$ if you are using the usual definition of $\arcsin: [-1,1] \to\left[-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right]$. As a function, $\arcsin$ can only give a single value

Graphically:

[image]

Comment: Not related to this question, but just to let you know that I asked a [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27389/the-birthday-tag) in meta concerning the tag "birthday". Hope you and more users familiar with probability can join the discussion there.

Answer (score 1):

(The range of arcsin is usually taken to be $[\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.)

$\textrm{sin}(5 \pi /4)=\textrm{sin}(-\pi/4)$, so you have $\textrm{sin}^{-1}(\textrm{sin}(5\pi /4))=\textrm{sin}^{-1}(\textrm{sin}(-\pi/4))=-\pi/4$